# Purpose of non-polar C1 - R1 in series

Tags: capacitor, switch-mode-power-supply

what is the purpose or function of series non-polar C1 - R1 (24 Ohm resistor) on parallel to rectifying D around SMPS output here ?
[image]

Help clarify by elaborated explanation, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is an RC snubber network.

As the diode is rapidly turned on and off, any stray inductances with stray capacitance can cause ringing or over/undershoots in the circuit

The RC snubber is tuned to catch and dampen those and the circuit emits less RF interference and the diode can work better without the high frequency bursts.

Comment: Should RC time is equal to or less than fraction of period time of Transformer output signal, in order to block it, or it's meant to pass that T output signal ?